# Jxl maven error

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver, jxl

when I run maven project it showing error as "package jxl does not exist "& "package jxl.read.biff does not exist". please help to resolve this. I am using JXl 2.6.3

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the package `jxl.read.biff` . Maybe it's not exist in the version of `JXL 2.6.3` so try this because it works for me :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```